# Is there a way to replace a function within a method in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

So what I'm trying to do is make  function that analyze algorithms that include their number of swaps and comparisons, now the problem I'm facing is that I need to reuse this function but in order to analyze the algorithm I need to call each algorithm function.

Here is the code of the function:

```
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (!flag)
        {
            selectionSort(bigArray[i], 100);
            printData(fileNames[i],swaps,comparisons);
            comparisons = 0;
            swaps = 0;
            flag = true;
        }
        else
        {
            selectionSort(bigArray[i], 1000);
            printData(fileNames[i],swaps,comparisons);
            comparisons = 0;
            swaps = 0;
            flag = false;
        }
    }
```

Now you see where selectionSort is I will need to replace it, with insertion,quick, heap, merge, counting. I could just write the code over and over again in the main and replace the sorting function, but I think there should be some sort of solution out there for doing this. I just can't find it, I was think of making a function that take another function as a parameter, but then again, some of the algorithms function take 2 other 3, and when doing that you can't just do `void analyzeAlgorithms(void (*function)(int*, int, int, int x = 0) ).` Any help would be appreciate it thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you use function pointers? If your problem is that some of your functions take two and some take three arguments, you can make the third parameter optional and ignore it when needed.

Comment: Another option is to make the function having a variadic template parameter pack, and forward it to a matching `std::function` parameter.

Comment: @Alex If I use a pointer function, as I said some algorithms take 2 or three. The c++ compiles forced you to implements the parameter such that  function(bigArray[i], 100, ????????).

Comment: You can use an object oriented solution.  Create an abstract Sorter class with a virtual sort() method.  Derive the specific HeapSort, MergeSort, InsertionSort classes that take different parameters in their constructors. Implement sort() for each. Then pass and call sort() on the specific instantiations.

Comment: @JulioRosario It would be nice to see the signature of your function also. What's `bigArray`, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your code within a function template taking a variadic parameter set, and forward that on the matching `Fn` callable parameter (I omitted some irrelevant stuff):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Fn, typename ...Args>
void sort_tester(Fn sortfunc, Args... args) {
    int bigArray[] {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        int n = flag ? 1000 : 100;
        sortfunc(bigArray[i],n,args...);
        flag = !flag;
    }
}

void selectionSort(int elem, int n) {
    std::cout << "selectionSort(" << elem << ',' << n << ")\n";
    // Do stuff ...
}

void mergeSort(int elem, int n, int extraParam) {
    std::cout << "mergeSort(" << elem << ',' << n << ',' << extraParam << ")\n";
    // Do stuff ...
}
```

This can be used like follows then:

```
int main() {
    sort_tester(selectionSort);

    sort_tester(mergeSort,42);
}
```

See the [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d65861cef2866b8d).

Comment: May I recommend not using `std::function` for that, but just a normal template parameter instead? Right now it requires `Args` to perfectly match parameter, not allowing conversions. if you replace `std::function<...>` with a simple template parameter, conversions will happen, and will likely be much lighter.

Comment: `std::function` gives you type enforcement (which can be good or bad, depending on your use case), but it also gives you extra indirection and a heap allocation.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Thanks for your advice. I simplified my code example using a plain template parameter instead of `std::function` now.

Answer (score 1):

Having the signature of your function would have helped, so I'll assume the variable types and parameter. If you wish a more complete solution, edit your question to add the actual relevant data to solve your problem.

You can pass the function to replace as a parameter.

```
template<typename F>
void yourAlgorithm(char const** fileNames, int** bigArray, F function) {
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (!flag)
        {
            function(bigArray[i], 100);
            printData(fileNames[i],swaps,comparisons);
            comparisons = 0;
            swaps = 0;
            flag = true;
        }
        else
        {
            function(bigArray[i], 1000);
            printData(fileNames[i],swaps,comparisons);
            comparisons = 0;
            swaps = 0;
            flag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

When calling it, you can pass a function or a lambda:

```
int n = 2;
yourAlgorithm(fileNames, bigArray, selectionSort);
yourAlgorithm(fileNames, bigArray, mergeSort);
yourAlgorithm(fileNames, bigArray, [n](int* a, int x){ /* do stuff with a, b and n */ });
```

Comment: As I understood OP's question is how to call the sort algorithms (functions) with a varying number of parameters. This needs to imply a variadic parameter pack IMO.

Comment: @Guillaume Racicot you were on point with the parameters (: . However user0042 is right, the function is for a varying number of parameters.

Comment: I like the use of a template for the method, here, but a pointer to a `char*` and a pointer to an `int*` are not very clean ways to pass array references around...

Comment: @caps I know. But as I said, I was trying to guess the type of the variable OP used. As he pointed out in the second comment, I was on spot with his types.